# Check if initial value problem has unique solution using Picard-Lindelöf

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Given the differential equation

$f'(t)=\frac{e^tf(t)^3}{1+f(t)^2}+tcos(f(t))$

how would one find out whether this problem has an unique solution?

I think I should use Picard-Lindelöf which says that if there is a Lipschitz constant L so that

$||F(x, y)−F(x, z)|| ≤ L||y−z||$
where $f'(t)=F(t,f(t))$

the problem should indeed have an unique solution.

I tried to plug in the x,y,z values in the formula but that gives me a really complicated fraction and I don't seem to find a way to simplify it so that I get an L (or not because according to the task it's also possible that the problem does have multiple solutions so in that case I need to prove that L is not limited).

Comment: If $F$ is $C^1$ then it is locally Lipschitz with respect to the space variable and you are in the scope of Picard-Lindelöf.

Comment: Can you explain why?

Comment: Use the mean value theorem together with the fact that a continuous function over a compact set has a maximum.